# International drivers license in Scotland

Tags: driving, scotland

Is an international drivers license required for Americans driving in Scotland?

Comment: Anecdotally, I'm a UK citizen, but been living in the US for 20 years. The last time I rented a car at Glasgow airport I had no problems using my Connecticut drivers license.

Comment: The International Driving Permit is not a license, and it's not even technically a permit. It's a _translation_ of your existing license into English and a few other languages.

Answer (score 2):

According to Gov.Uk (link below)If you are a visitor to Great Britain and passed your driving test in another country "You can drive any small vehicle (eg car or motorcycle) listed on your full and valid licence for 12 months from when you last entered Great Britain (GB)".Great Britain is England, Wales and Scotland     https://www.gov.uk/driving-nongb-licence/y/a-visitor-to-great-britain/any-other-country

Answer (score 0):

It’s not a legal requirement. However, some rental companies may require it.